# Chrome and Edge hardware acceleration on 22.04 with Intel Alder Lake

Tags: drivers, graphics, laptop, intel-graphics, intel

I'm running Ubuntu on a live USB to have a look at 22.04 features (not using Linux pretty much since 2012) on my new Asus Vivobook 15 X1502ZA (i5-1240p - 8 GB - 250 GB NVMe). Although I'd like to, I'm still afraid of installing Ubuntu permanently on this laptop because of low performance when running 4K videos on YouTube (1080p works fine even 60fps videos).

I've run the same test on KDE Neon, Kubuntu and Manjaro all of them on Live USB with same results. Also tried enabling VAAPI on Firefox, installing `ìntel-media-va-driver` and `intel-media-va-driver-non-free`. Watching a remux movie in 4K with VLC and VA-API enabled works fine.

It's kinda weird because almost everyone knows that Intel drivers are integrated in the kernel. (version `5.15.0-43-generic`). First guess was that I shouldn't have any problems.
I've read that you need 5.16 kernel or newer for better performance on Intel Alder Lake systems but IIRC one of the distros I tried had 5.19 kernel installed.

iGPU on Windows is named Intel UHD Graphics (without XXX number), i'm pretty sure it is Xe compatible in case I add another SODIMM. Needless to say but of course graphics performance on Windows is good and there aren't any issues.

Should I try to install Ubuntu on my NVMe local drive to see if these problems disappear? Is it worth it? Can it be because I'm running the OS on a live USB?

Thank you :)

EDIT

Interesting fact. Made 4K 60fps YouTube videos work fine both on Pop os and KDE Neon, both with `intel-media-driver-va`, `media.ffmpeg.vaapi.enabled` enabled and `media.ffvpx.enabled` disabled. Bad news is that I dislike Firefox and prefer Chrome or Edge, and both of which have hardware acceleration permanently disabled in the `chrome://flags` and `edge://flags` sections. Worth mentioning that CPU usage when watching videos in Ubuntu is practically 100% against less than 20% on Pop os and KDE Neon. This facts makes me believe that I'll have the same performance with the OS permanently installed on my computer. Now I think it's pretty clear that this may be happening because of hardware acceleration issues and not because of USB bottleneck or live memory.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4621 (rev 02)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
0000:00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51be (rev 01)
0000:00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH UART #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:1e.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 51aa (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN550 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
ubuntu@ubuntu
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 2
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       nombre lógico: /dev/fb0
       versión: 0c
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuración: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       recursos: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:162 memoria:6002000000-6002ffffff memoria:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memoria:c0000-dffff memoria:4010000000-4016ffffff memoria:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Comment: I’ve definitely experienced very different graphics performance in a live session compared with a full installation. As it’s a new laptop, I probably would try it in your position - presumably not too much wasted time if it doesn’t perform and you have to revert to Windows?